# How push to a Vec such that the entry is inserted in alphabetical order to avoid sorting later?

Tags: rust

I am adding entries to a vector and sorting it after insertion:

```rust
struct EntryId(String);

fn main() {
  let mut all_entries = Vec::<(EntryId, PathBuf)>::new();

  for (entry_id, entry_path) in get_entries() {
    all_entries.push((entry_id.clone(), entry_path.clone()))
  }  
  all_entries.sort_by(|a, b| a.1.cmp(&b.1));
}
```

However sorting takes a very long time as I have millions of entries and have to sort multiple times (not all insertions occur in the same place)

I don't really care if the order is alphabetical, it just needs to be deterministic. In my case I am sorting alphabetically against the `PathBuf` because that's a consistent key.

I am wondering if it's possible to insert into a `Vec` alphabetically or if there is a better data structure to use for this?

I tried using a `BTreeSet<(EntryId, PathBuf)>` however the order did not appear deterministic (perhaps because the `EntryId` is dynamically generated).

Would a `BTreeMap<PathBuf, EntryId>` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key needs to be the thing you want to sort by. So yes, `BTreeMap<PathBuf, EntryId>` will work.

Another alternative is to store them in a `Vec`, but keep the sorted order. You can do that easily with [`binary_search()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search). It (and its friends) return the index of the element if found, **or the index it needs to be inserted in to maintain sorted order** if not:

```rust
fn insert_entry(all_entries: &mut Vec<(EntryId, PathBuf)>, new_entry: (EntryId, PathBuf)) {
    let Err(index_to_insert) = all_entries.binary_search_by_key(&&new_entry.1, |entry| &entry.1)
    else {
        // Entry already exists.
        return;
    };
    all_entries.insert(index_to_insert, new_entry);
}
```

A `Vec` will have faster iteration and access when you know the index, while a `BTreeMap` will have faster access when you know only the order and way faster insertion (due to the need to shift all elements on insertion in `Vec`).